# VOD iOS playback shows "Loading..." and does not load for short videos

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, video-streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller

Some of my short VOD clips fail to play in iOS (iOS6, iPad, Simulator). The first frame loads, but the video never plays - the loading message and spinner stay forever. Other short videos play successfully. I can view the videos with no problem in Safari on Mac, in VLC on Windows, Android, etc. It is only on iOS (Safari, UIWebView and MPMoviePlayerController) that the problem manifests itself.

playlist.m3u8:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=256477,CODECS="avc1.66.30",RESOLUTION=640x480
chunklist.m3u8?wowzasessionid=1850863335
```

chunklist.m3u8:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXTINF:3.972, media_1.ts?wowzasessionid=1850863335
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

mediavalidatortool:

```
mediastreamvalidator http://<url>/video_9ac61783a189a96cea3c93a3f995cae6db3ef7a2_1379387221.mp4/playlist.m3u8
mediastreamvalidator: Beta Version 1.1(130423)

Validating http://<url>/video_9ac61783a189a96cea3c93a3f995cae6db3ef7a2_1379387221.mp4/playlist.m3u8
Validating child playlist chunklist.m3u8?wowzasessionid=33067098 [256.48 kbits/sec]

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
http://<url>/video_9ac61783a189a96cea3c93a3f995cae6db3ef7a2_1379387221.mp4/playlist.m3u8
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Playlist Syntax:      OK

Alternate playlist(s):

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
chunklist.m3u8?wowzasessionid=33067098
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Playlist Syntax:      OK

Segments:     OK

Average segment duration: 3.02 seconds
Playlist target bitrate: 256.48 kbits/sec
Segment bitrate: Average: 243.85 kbits/sec, Max: 243.85 kbits/sec
```

We are using Amazon S3 and MediaCache. We have no issues with video playback except on iOS for certain (but not all) short video clips.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Daniel

**Edit:** This appears to only occur with videos under 14 seconds created from a specific source, this may be an encoder issue. Will update with findings when I return to this issue.